# string literal uniqueness requirements

Tags: c++

I've always understood that the storage of string literals is implementation defined, so the compiler is free to roll up multiple literals such that, given

```
static const char* foo = "blah";
static const char* bar = "blah";
```

foo and bar can point to the same memory. However, I can't figure out if thats also true when:

```
static const char foo[] = "blah";
static const char bar[] = "blah";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>A well-formed program cannot tell whether `foo` and `blah` are stored at the same address or not, so I believe that yes the optimizer could fold the constants together.</strike>

`[expr.rel]` (draft 3225) says:

> If two pointers `p` and `q` of the same type point to diﬀerent objects that are not members of the same
>   object or elements of the same array or to diﬀerent functions, or if only one of them is `null`, the results
>   of `p<q`, `p>q`, `p<=q`, and `p>=q` are unspeciﬁed.

`[expr.eq]` says:

> The `==` (equal to) and the `!=` (not equal to) operators have the same semantic restrictions, conversions, and
>   result type as the relational operators except for their lower precedence and truth-value result.

`[expr.add]` says:

> When two pointers to elements of the same array object are subtracted

(snip)

> Unless both pointers point to elements of the same array object, or
>   one past the last element of the array object, the behavior is undeﬁned.

---

FOOTNOTE: **This has to be wrong**, but it's my interpretation of what the standard says.  I'd love to see the section of the **C++ standard** that overrules this language.

I think it may be this:

`[intro.object]` says:

> Two distinct objects that are neither bit-ﬁelds nor base class subobjects of zero
>   size shall have distinct addresses.

`[expr.eq]` says:

> Two pointers of the same type compare equal if
>   and only if they are both null, both point to the same function, or both represent the same address

So in conclusion, yes you could tell if the arrays were folded, so they can't be.  But most ways of telling have unspecified results, you have to use `==` or `!=` directly on pointers.  As @aschelper points out, `std::less` and its relations will also work.

Comment: A well-formed program in fact can tell. `foo` and `bar` are distinct different objects, therefore they have to have different addresses.

Comment: A well formed program can obtain the addresses of the two and compare, and it will notice the difference.

Comment: You should be able to tell with `const char *a = foo, b = bar; std::cout << (a == b) ? "yes" : "no" << std::endl;` Direct pointer comparison ought to work for this purpose. (There's no reason to ask, but it still seems like you should be able to tell.)

Comment: @David: Comparing pointers only has a defined result when both are into the same array or object.  That's not the case here.

Comment: @Ben - I'm citing C99 (not C++) standard but: "Two pointers compare equal if and only if both are null pointers, both are pointers to the same object (including a pointer to an object and a subobject at its beginning) or function, both are pointers to one past the last element of the same array object, or one is a pointer to one past the end of one array object and the other is a pointer to the start of a different array object that happens to immediately follow the first array object in the address space.)"

Comment: @Ben: Comparing pointers from different complete objects has implementation-defined behavior, not UB.  Implementation-defined behavior does not make a program ill-formed.

Comment: A common case in C++ is testing whether an argument passed to a copy constructor is the same object as `this` with `this == &p`. This should be expected to work, otherwise there is no safe way to test whether or not two objects are the same, and almost all pointer equality tests are unsafe unless they test against `NULL` or they're used in iterators to test against `i.end()`.

Comment: @Chris: The question is tagged `c++`, not `c`.

Comment: Whats the rule that says &foo != &bar ?

Comment: @Chris: There are a large number of "debug iterators" out there that abort if you try to do equality comparison against an iterator from another container.

Comment: @Ben: Also, if you're going to interpret those requirements that way, it's invalid to compare a non-null pointer to a null pointer using `==` and `!=`, right?

Comment: @aschepler: No, the "only one of them is null" case was specifically allowed.  But `(p1 - p2) != 0` is invalid if one is null and the other is not.

Comment: @Ben - Read the full `expr.eq`: "The == (equal to) and the != (not equal to) operators have the same semantic restrictions, conversions, and result type as the relational operators except for their lower precedence and truth-value result. [ Note: a<b == c<d is true whenever 
a<b and c<d have the same truth-value. — end note ] **Pointers to objects or functions of the same type (after pointer conversions) can be compared for equality. Two pointers of the same type compare equal if and only if they are both null, both point to the same function, or both represent the same address.**"

Comment: @Ben: I agree - the "Pointers .. can be compared" sentence means "the same semantic restrictions" specified for relational operators are relaxed in the case of pointers.

Comment: Another portable way to test: check for an equivalence relation using `std::less<const char*>`.

Comment: @Chris: The issue is that if-and-only-if implications can be used in either direction.  That rule permits the following interpretation: "Relational operators between pointers to different objects have unspecified semantics" + "Equality operators have the same semantics as relational operators" => "Equality operators between pointers to different objects have unspecified semantics" + "Pointers represent the same address iff they compare equal" => "Whether the pointers have the same address is unspecified".  But the wording in `[basic.object]` does not allow that interpretation.

Comment: @aschepler: Nice.  " For templates `greater`, `less`, `greater_equal`, and `less_equal`, the specializations for any pointer type
yield a total order, even if the built-in operators `<`, `>`, `<=`, `>=` do not.", section `[comparisons]`.

Comment: C++03, 5.10/1 [expr.eq] *Pointers to objects or functions of
the same type (after pointer conversions) can be compared for equality. Two pointers of the same type compare equal if and only if they are both null, both point to the same function, or both represent the same address (3.9.2).* @Ben, there is a huge difference between *relational* operators (`<,>,<=,>=`) and equality comparison. Pointers **can** be compared for equality, what is not defined is the order in memory of different objects when they are not subobjects of a common element.

Comment: @David: Yes, there is a huge difference between relational operators and equality comparison.  So why does the standard say "The == (equal to) and the != (not equal to) operators have the same semantic restrictions, conversions, and result type as the relational operators except for their lower precedence and truth-value result.", which suggests they're semantically equivalent after all?

Comment: And what are the semantic restrictions? 5.9/2 states that the result of the relational operator comparisons on pointers is unspecified if the objects are not a subobject of a common object, not that you cannot semantically do it. Then 5.10/1 states taht the result of the equality comparison of two pointers of the same type is completely defined for any two objects of the same type: they are equal if they refer to the same location and thus the same object. That comment was most probably added to avoid having to duplicate the whole set of conversions that can occur and pitfalls (ambiguities...)

Comment: Note that *unspecified* means that the program is correct, but that the result (one from a set of possible results) is not mandated by the standard. That is, given two objects `a` and `b` declared as `type a,b;` the standard does not mandate whether they have to be allocated in memory in increasing order or not, the implementation is allowed to place `a` before or after `b` (while it does require that ordering when `a` and `b` are part of a greater object). At the same time the standard mandates that different objects are placed at different addresses, so `&a!=&b` regardless of whether `&a<&b`

Comment: @David: right, all that is quoted in my answer.  I seem to have trouble finding rules in the "intro" section, because it's not organized nearly as well as the rest of the standard.

Answer (score 1):

In the second case, you are declaring two arrays, and each one of them will have a different address. So no, the addresses will not be the same.

You can easily test it by printing the address of `foo` and `bar` (in both cases, `&foo != &bar`, but that in the first case only means that the pointers are in different locations, while in the second case it means that the arrays are in different locations: `(void*)&foo == (void*)&foo[0]` for the array case)

Comment: Correct, though the actual constants used to initialize them might still be merged. On another note, things are even more complicated than just "implementation detail", it may even make a difference whether the constants are in the same translation unit or not. For example my copy of gcc 4.5 will happily merge constants as in the first example within the same unit, but not within different units (which are linked into one program).

Answer (score 1):

@Ben Voight cited the Standard:

> **[intro.object]** says:
>   Two distinct objects that are neither bit-ﬁelds nor base class subobjects of zero size shall have distinct addresses.

But there is another rule in the standard that is equally important: the *as-if* rule.

That is, the standard guarantees that two distinct objects of which you observe the address shall be distinct.

But, as far as I understand it, *if the compiler can prove* that you do not observe the address of one object, it could merge it with an existing one (and since you do not observe its address, you would not realize it!)

Could it be a typical case of the measure perturbing the experiment :) ?

Answer (score 0):

In the second case, the two variables are actually arrays, and hence they would definitely point to **different** location.

```
static const char foo[] = "blah";
static const char bar[] = "blah";
cout << sizeof(foo) << " : " << (void*)foo << endl;
cout << sizeof(bar) << " : " << (void*)bar << endl;
```

Output: **(5 is the size of array)**

```
5 : 0x8048a99
5 : 0x8048a94
```

See output here : http://www.ideone.com/hoH5v
(when you run, the address may be different however than shown above)

---

In the first case however, both are pointers and would point to the **same** location (for most compilers)!

```
static const char *foo = "blah";
static const char *bar = "blah";
cout << sizeof(foo) << " : " << (void*)foo << endl;
cout << sizeof(bar) << " : " << (void*)bar << endl;
```

Output: **(now 4 is the size of pointer)**

```
4 : 0x8048a94
4 : 0x8048a94
```

Did you notice the address is same for both pointers?

See : http://www.ideone.com/keaoC

Comment: You can't definitively state an optimization is disallowed based on a single compiler that chooses not to do it.